# Android: How do I get a list of installed applications and show them to the user

Tags: java, android, listview, flags, intentfilter

I've looked at many different variations of code on how to get a list of installed applications and show them in a ListView to the user but none have been successful for me. What I'd like to know is how to do this and how I'd add flags(?) to it so that I could just list curtain applications which have different intent-filters such as LONG_SEARCH_BUTTON and be able to view the package and launcher class of that application.. if this is do able?

I'd like a full java class if someone wouldn't mind sharing their knowledge as trying to piece together bits of code is becoming quite stressful! I've been coding android for a few months so I know most of the basic stuff (I'd like to think...) but not don't anything like this before.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a short application which does exactly that... check it out [**here**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/09/tutorial-loader-loadermanager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code from the Android documentation. Please be creative for your requirements.

> /**  * This class holds the per-item data in our Loader.  */ public
>   static class AppEntry {
>       public AppEntry(AppListLoader loader, ApplicationInfo info) {
>           mLoader = loader;
>           mInfo = info;
>           mApkFile = new File(info.sourceDir);
>       }
>
> ```
> public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() {
>     return mInfo;
> }
>
> public String getLabel() {
>     return mLabel;
> }
>
> public Drawable getIcon() {
>     if (mIcon == null) {
>         if (mApkFile.exists()) {
>             mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mLoader.mPm);
>             return mIcon;
>         } else {
>             mMounted = false;
>         }
>     } else if (!mMounted) {
>         // If the app wasn't mounted but is now mounted, reload
>         // its icon.
>         if (mApkFile.exists()) {
>             mMounted = true;
>             mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mLoader.mPm);
>             return mIcon;
>         }
>     } else {
>         return mIcon;
>     }
>
>     return mLoader.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
>             android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
> }
>
> @Override public String toString() {
>     return mLabel;
> }
>
> void loadLabel(Context context) {
>     if (mLabel == null || !mMounted) {
>         if (!mApkFile.exists()) {
>             mMounted = false;
>             mLabel = mInfo.packageName;
>         } else {
>             mMounted = true;
>             CharSequence label = mInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager());
>             mLabel = label != null ? label.toString() : mInfo.packageName;
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> private final AppListLoader mLoader;
> private final ApplicationInfo mInfo;
> private final File mApkFile;
> private String mLabel;
> private Drawable mIcon;
> private boolean mMounted; }
> ```
>
> /**  * Perform alphabetical comparison of application entry objects. 
>   */ public static final Comparator ALPHA_COMPARATOR = new Comparator() {
>       private final Collator sCollator = Collator.getInstance();
>       @Override
>       public int compare(AppEntry object1, AppEntry object2) {
>           return sCollator.compare(object1.getLabel(), object2.getLabel());
>       } };
>
> /**  * Helper for determining if the configuration has changed in an
>   interesting  * way so we need to rebuild the app list.  */ public
>   static class InterestingConfigChanges {
>       final Configuration mLastConfiguration = new Configuration();
>       int mLastDensity;
>
> ```
> boolean applyNewConfig(Resources res) {
>     int configChanges = mLastConfiguration.updateFrom(res.getConfiguration());
>     boolean densityChanged = mLastDensity != res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
>     if (densityChanged || (configChanges&(ActivityInfo.CONFIG_LOCALE
>             |ActivityInfo.CONFIG_UI_MODE|ActivityInfo.CONFIG_SCREEN_LAYOUT)) != 0)
> ```
>
> {
>               mLastDensity = res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
>               return true;
>           }
>           return false;
>       } }
>
> /**  * Helper class to look for interesting changes to the installed
>   apps  * so that the loader can be updated.  */ public static class
>   PackageIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>       final AppListLoader mLoader;
>
> ```
> public PackageIntentReceiver(AppListLoader loader) {
>     mLoader = loader;
>     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
>     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
>     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
>     filter.addDataScheme("package");
>     mLoader.getContext().registerReceiver(this, filter);
>     // Register for events related to sdcard installation.
>     IntentFilter sdFilter = new IntentFilter();
>     sdFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
>     sdFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE);
>     mLoader.getContext().registerReceiver(this, sdFilter);
> }
>
> @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>     // Tell the loader about the change.
>     mLoader.onContentChanged();
> } }
> ```
>
> /**  * A custom Loader that loads all of the installed applications. 
>   */ public static class AppListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader> {
>       final InterestingConfigChanges mLastConfig = new InterestingConfigChanges();
>       final PackageManager mPm;
>
> ```
> List<AppEntry> mApps;
> PackageIntentReceiver mPackageObserver;
>
> public AppListLoader(Context context) {
>     super(context);
>
>     // Retrieve the package manager for later use; note we don't
>     // use 'context' directly but instead the save global application
>     // context returned by getContext().
>     mPm = getContext().getPackageManager();
> }
>
> /**
>  * This is where the bulk of our work is done.  This function is
>  * called in a background thread and should generate a new set of
>  * data to be published by the loader.
>  */
> @Override public List<AppEntry> loadInBackground() {
>     // Retrieve all known applications.
>     List<ApplicationInfo> apps = mPm.getInstalledApplications(
>             PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES |
>             PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);
>     if (apps == null) {
>         apps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
>     }
>
>     final Context context = getContext();
>
>     // Create corresponding array of entries and load their labels.
>     List<AppEntry> entries = new ArrayList<AppEntry>(apps.size());
>     for (int i=0; i<apps.size(); i++) {
>         AppEntry entry = new AppEntry(this, apps.get(i));
>         entry.loadLabel(context);
>         entries.add(entry);
>     }
>
>     // Sort the list.
>     Collections.sort(entries, ALPHA_COMPARATOR);
>
>     // Done!
>     return entries;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Called when there is new data to deliver to the client.  The
>  * super class will take care of delivering it; the implementation
>  * here just adds a little more logic.
>  */
> @Override public void deliverResult(List<AppEntry> apps) {
>     if (isReset()) {
>         // An async query came in while the loader is stopped.  We
>         // don't need the result.
>         if (apps != null) {
>             onReleaseResources(apps);
>         }
>     }
>     List<AppEntry> oldApps = apps;
>     mApps = apps;
>
>     if (isStarted()) {
>         // If the Loader is currently started, we can immediately
>         // deliver its results.
>         super.deliverResult(apps);
>     }
>
>     // At this point we can release the resources associated with
>     // 'oldApps' if needed; now that the new result is delivered we
>     // know that it is no longer in use.
>     if (oldApps != null) {
>         onReleaseResources(oldApps);
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Handles a request to start the Loader.
>  */
> @Override protected void onStartLoading() {
>     if (mApps != null) {
>         // If we currently have a result available, deliver it
>         // immediately.
>         deliverResult(mApps);
>     }
>
>     // Start watching for changes in the app data.
>     if (mPackageObserver == null) {
>         mPackageObserver = new PackageIntentReceiver(this);
>     }
>
>     // Has something interesting in the configuration changed since we
>     // last built the app list?
>     boolean configChange = mLastConfig.applyNewConfig(getContext().getResources());
>
>     if (takeContentChanged() || mApps == null || configChange) {
>         // If the data has changed since the last time it was loaded
>         // or is not currently available, start a load.
>         forceLoad();
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
>  */
> @Override protected void onStopLoading() {
>     // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
>     cancelLoad();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Handles a request to cancel a load.
>  */
> @Override public void onCanceled(List<AppEntry> apps) {
>     super.onCanceled(apps);
>
>     // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
>     // if needed.
>     onReleaseResources(apps);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
>  */
> @Override protected void onReset() {
>     super.onReset();
>
>     // Ensure the loader is stopped
>     onStopLoading();
>
>     // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
>     // if needed.
>     if (mApps != null) {
>         onReleaseResources(mApps);
>         mApps = null;
>     }
>
>     // Stop monitoring for changes.
>     if (mPackageObserver != null) {
>         getContext().unregisterReceiver(mPackageObserver);
>         mPackageObserver = null;
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated
>  * with an actively loaded data set.
>  */
> protected void onReleaseResources(List<AppEntry> apps) {
>     // For a simple List<> there is nothing to do.  For something
>     // like a Cursor, we would close it here.
> } }
> ```

An example implementation of a fragment that uses the above loader to show the currently installed applications in a list is below.

> public static class AppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
>       private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
>
> ```
> public AppListAdapter(Context context) {
>     super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
>     mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> }
>
> public void setData(List<AppEntry> data) {
>     clear();
>     if (data != null) {
>         addAll(data);
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Populate new items in the list.
>  */
> @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     View view;
>
>     if (convertView == null) {
>         view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, parent, false);
>     } else {
>         view = convertView;
>     }
>
>     AppEntry item = getItem(position);
>     ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());
>     ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getLabel());
>
>     return view;
> } }
> ```
>
> public static class AppListFragment extends ListFragment
>           implements OnQueryTextListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks> {
>
> ```
> // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
> AppListAdapter mAdapter;
>
> // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
> String mCurFilter;
>
> @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
>
>     // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
>     // application this would come from a resource.
>     setEmptyText("No applications");
>
>     // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
>     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
>
>     // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
>     mAdapter = new AppListAdapter(getActivity());
>     setListAdapter(mAdapter);
>
>     // Start out with a progress indicator.
>     setListShown(false);
>
>     // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
>     // or start a new one.
>     getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
> }
>
> @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
>     // Place an action bar item for searching.
>     MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
>     item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
>     item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
>             | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
>     SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
>     sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
>     item.setActionView(sv);
> }
>
> @Override public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
>     // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Since this
>     // is a simple array adapter, we can just have it do the filtering.
>     mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
>     mAdapter.getFilter().filter(mCurFilter);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
>     // Don't care about this.
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
>     // Insert desired behavior here.
>     Log.i("LoaderCustom", "Item clicked: " + id);
> }
>
> @Override public Loader<List<AppEntry>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
>     // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
>     // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
>     return new AppListLoader(getActivity());
> }
>
> @Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader, List<AppEntry> data) {
>     // Set the new data in the adapter.
>     mAdapter.setData(data);
>
>     // The list should now be shown.
>     if (isResumed()) {
>         setListShown(true);
>     } else {
>         setListShownNoAnimation(true);
>     }
> }
>
> @Override public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader) {
>     // Clear the data in the adapter.
>     mAdapter.setData(null);
> } }
> ```